# Satis with private repo update Workflow

Tags: composer-php, workflow, satis

i Have a private repo on GitHub and configured Satis on my server.

Satis have only one tag i speficied called 0.9.1

Everithing working fine, i use the composer create-project command to create a new project on my computer with the repo contents, install composer dependencies,  etc.

**Now the question**

suppose the repo continues development and now i have a tag called 0.9.2.

How can i update the project on my machine with the new repo tag.

I need to do additional tasks on the satis server?
I need to run some command on my machine?
Whats the best workflow for this scenario?

Tranks

**UPDATE**

My private repo on github
https://github.com/pablonunez-dev/myproject

Files on my repo.

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
composer.json
```

this is the content of the composer.json file

```
{
"name": "myproject",
"description": "myproject",
"keywords": ["myproject", "application template"],
"homepage": "http://www.myserver.net/",
"type": "project",
"license": "BSD-3-Clause",
"support": {
    "issues": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/issues?state=open",
    "forum": "http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/",
    "wiki": "http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/",
    "irc": "irc://irc.freenode.net/yii",
    "source": "https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2"
},
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"require": {
    "php": ">=5.4.0",
    "yiisoft/yii2": "2.0.7"
},
"extra": {
    "asset-installer-paths": {
        "npm-asset-library": "vendor/npm",
        "bower-asset-library": "vendor/bower"
    }
}
```

}

this is my project configuration file on satis

```
{
    "name": "My Satis Packages Server",
    "homepage": "http://satis.myserver.net",
    "repositories": [
        { "type": "vcs", "url": "https://github.com/pablonunez-dev/myproject
          ],
    "require":
    {
        "myproject/core":"0.9.*"
    }
}
```

Now, when i go to my computer and run.

```
C:\composer create-project myproject/core test1 --repository-url=http://satis.myserver.net
```

It work well and create the folder and install dependencies from composer.json with the structure

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
vendor
composer.json
composer.lock
```

Now, the problem is, when i go to my repository and delete de file file1.txt and create another one with the name file3.txt,  commit, push, recreate satis

**How can i update the folder on my machine with the repo changes?**

Thanks, again

Answer (score 2):

It's best to have a script or one-click-job that does all the Satis update calls you need.

In general, your workflow would be like this:

1. Update the software, commit and push it, and tag it with a new version number. Push the tag.
2. Update the Satis repo data.
3. Update your main package with `composer update` - this should fetch the new tag of the package.

Updating Satis probably is only one simple command line call, but it has parameters with files, and you don't want to remember them. Just add a simple shell script `satis-update` that calls Satis with the correct parameters. If possible, create a job on Jenkins or Bamboo or wherever that allows you to click a button that starts the update.

The best solution would be to add post-commit triggers to all repos that start the update once a tag has been pushed, but this is advanced. My own Satis instance hosts 120 internal packages, and Satis runs either once each night, or manually on demand if a developer needs the update quicker. It takes about 5 minutes to finish.

Note that you can omit the Satis update cycle by adding the repository you are developing with as an additional vcs repo. That way your main package can query the repository directly, and will know about new tags instantly. However, this is only really recommended during development times.

Comment: Thanks @Sven, that is the info i need to know if i am going on the best direction,  right now i am testing the point #3 of the workflow you describe.

Comment: well, i test the point #3 and didn't work.  on satis i have only one repo,  this repo is a complete site development under yii,  with a lot of folders and their own composer.json file.
When i run composer create-project .... --repository-url=mysatisserver it work well,  create the project with the entire repo content and install all the dependencies from ther composer.json file, but i lost the connection with satis becouse there is no place where is pointed so i dont know how to update the project (not the dependencies),  thanks